# The prop `children` is marked as required in `AppBar`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use native Material-ui component but have this error in browser :

index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `AppBar`, but its value is `undefined`.

My component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

/**
 * A simple example of `AppBar` with an icon on the right.
 * By default, the left icon is a navigation-menu.
 */
const Header = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
  />
);

export default Header;
```

Help me to understand why?

Comment: What is version of the material-ui?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with `^1.0.0-beta.38` and I found solution. This caused by incompatibility with new library api. According to issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6446, library actively reworking now, but documentation have not updated yet. It seems, that new version library provide required children validation props for AppBar component. if you look at react dev-tool inspector you will see that AppBar have not children at Props:[image]

Logically, you need to put children node ToolBar and Typography children into AppBar like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppBar } from 'material-ui'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
            Title
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar> 
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}
```

Into react inspector you could see new child prop.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question when getting the following error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required
> in `ForwardRef(Container)`, but its value is `undefined`.

The problem was that without realising I had stupidly removed all the children from a `<Container>` element. I didn't understand the error message straight away and the error didn't point clearly to a file in project so leaving this answer here in case others make the same silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The children is the component embraced by your main component, so it should be :

```
<AppBar
  title="Title"
  iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
>
  <ChildrenComponent />
</AppBar>
```

If you don't need any children, you don't have to put it as required.

Answer (score 0):

When it runs for the first time as there is no value in Props , so it will come up as `undefined` , you can avoid this error be setting `defaultProps` and giving it a property `isNotNull`:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

ComponentName.defaultProps = {
  input: PropTypes.isNotNull // you can amend this accordingly
}
```

**NOTE** : If you want to allow null use `isDefined` and if you want to allow `undefined` then use `isNotNull` like (You can amend it accordignly):

```
PropTypes.string.isDefined // allows null but not undefined
PropTypes.string.isNotNull // allows undefined but not null
```

You can read more about Typechecking with propTypes [On React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was Getting this error while using a theme wrapper in Gatsby.  The error only exists in development mode, and once build and served it goes away.